# extraParams not updating on extjs pagination

Tags: extjs, extjs4.1

In my proxy i set a custom param with global variable "contactType" that is set at the header of my html page

```
 proxy:{
        type:'ajax',
        api:{
            read: '/Contact/read',
        },
        extraParams : {
            'contactType' : contactType
        }
    },
```

this works well, i then update my grid

```
contactType = "courier";
var contactStore = this.getContactsStore();
contactStore.load({
    scope:this,
    params:{contactType:contactType}
});
```

This also works well and the value "courier" is added as a param. My issue is that when i click on the pagination buttons the param does not reflect the new value. "courier"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Explicitly update the extra param with `proxy.setExtraParam(name, value)` e.g.:

```
contactStore.proxy.setExtraParam('contactType', contactType);
```